# TCPDF logo header

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, tcpdf

I'm trying to get my logo show up in the header and centered.
I'm using Cakephp and my logo file is kki.jpg which is saved under images folder of TCPDF folder, TCPDF is also saved in vendor folder and PDF is working fine and this is also defined in config like below:

```
define ('K_PATH_IMAGES', '/images/');
```

Below is my code:

```
$tcpdf->SetAuthor("Likeslomakkeet");
$tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak( true, $footerHeight );
//$tcpdf->SetTopMargin(10);
$tcpdf->setHeaderFont(array($textfont,'',30));
//$tcpdf->SetMargins(20, 30);
$tcpdf->SetHeaderData("kki.jpg", PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, "Application PDF", "Likeslomakkeet - www.likeslomakkeet.net");
$tcpdf->xheadercolor = array(238,238,238);
$tcpdf->xheadertext = '';
$tcpdf->xfootertext = 'Copyright © %d Likeslomakkeet. All rights reserved.';
$tcpdf->AddPage();
$tcpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$tcpdf->SetFont($textfont,'',14);
```

I cannot get logo to show up in my header. Is there a reason why?

This is under view_pdf.ctp file by the way...

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message? Is the image in some strange, more unusual jpeg format (test this with a PNG image, for example?)

Comment: I did test it with png image but it's not working...strange huh?

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in the same config file.

```
define ('PDF_HEADER_LOGO', 'kki.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

tcpdf default url is  xxx\examples\images ,so you should put img into this url or set

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Deafult image logo used be the default Header() method.
 * Please set here your own logo or an empty string to disable it.
 */
define ('PDF_HEADER_LOGO', '');
```

rewrite this code in config tcpdf.php files